# Eclipse - spell checking inside String Quotes ""

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When using Eclipse spell check inside comments is enabled, but when entering for example :

```
String myString =  "why isnt this getttting cheackedd";
```

Eclipse isn't checking spelling inside quotes,

is there a option to set this enable ? or do i have to download a plugin for this matter ?

thanks

Comment: Workaround: add `// why isnt this getttting cheackedd` and you can know if it's correctly spelled.

Comment: this workaround is taking to much time ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to disable

> ***"Ignore Java String literals"*** under eclipse
>
> Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling.

[image]

Comment: Tip: Go `Window » Preferences` and type a word like "spell" into the search box in the upper left corner.